# inner function raise in Django rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I catch a **4XX** series raise in inner function of an API in Django rest framework?

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class DummyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        if id==something:
               dummy_function_1(id)
        else:
               dummy_function_2(id)

        return Response()


def dummy_function_1():
    try:
        validate_1(id)
    except ValidationError:
        raise ValidationError()

    #do something with id
    return id
```

When I send a HTTP GET request, I receive a **5XX** series error if exception occurs. I want to get **400 Bad Request** error in response.

Comment: why don't you add try-except statement in get function and handle exceptions there?

Comment: Because I use this functions in several places That's why I need it.

Comment: This might be of help https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

Comment: @crazychukz , I read it, it doesn't help me.

Comment: If I understand you very well, you want to change the error status code?

Comment: @crazychukz , Yes, But if I change status_code of exception error, will not effect. I tried it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of effort and I don't know why,
If I specify the **exception type** of inner function, I will get 5XX series error.
so in dummy function I just wrote :

```
def dummy_function_1():
    try:
        validate_1(id)
    except Exception:    # just exception, Not ValidationError or other exception
        raise ValidationError()
```

I could get 4XX series error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def dummy_function_1():
    try:
        validate_1(id)
    except Exception:  # just exception, Not ValidationError or other exceptions
        raise ValidationError()
```